# Issues opening projects on my Teacher's computer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am a high school student working in Visual Basic on VS2019 and using .NET 5.0, my teacher is using VS2015 and using .NET 4.5.2, we are having difficulties opening my projects on his computer. This is the error in the output log

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML
> namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
> please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
> to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
> 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  D:\DiceRoll03\DiceRoll03\DiceRoll03.vbproj

If anyone understands this or has seen this problem before, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Net 5.0** projects only be supported on at least **VS2019 16.8**.  See [this document](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/).

[image]

It means the vs versions before that do not support NET 5.0 including VS2015.

So you should let your teacher's computer [download the latest VS2019 community free version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) and then you can work with that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will inform him about this.

Comment: Sure. Please download VS2019 to work with your project. And if it works, please do not forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not, please feel free to let us know:)